# C++, undefined reference to simple class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, netbeans-8, undefined-reference

I'm using Netbeans IDE8.2 of Linux. The following very simple code is not accepted:

```
class Instrument
{
public:
    Instrument();
    void MakeSound(){
        cout<<"Instrument plays..."<<endl;
    }
    virtual ~Instrument();
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Instrument inst;
//    Instrument* inst = new Instrument();
    cout<<"Start"<<endl;
    
    cout<<"End"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler says:  `undefined reference to Instrument::Instrument()` 
I don't know why.

Comment: That's because you forgot to implement `Instrument::Instrument()` (and destructor as well).

Comment: You *declare* the constructor and destructor functions, but you never *define* (implement) them. Either add their definition (implementation) or remove the declarations.